# Read txt file by chunks with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas gives you the feature of reading CSV and SQL queries by chunks, how could I do that with .txt files?

Comment: Can't you not read your `.txt` by `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: My bad, read_csv works with txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .txt file follows some pattern with a specific separator, you can use pandas read_csv.

Or I will recommend you to read the file with open() function, do some parsing, and create a dataframe with the result